# Force InfoPath to open in browser, from Tasks Hyperlink

Tags: infopath, form, browser-compatibility

My project team has created an InfoPath form for gathering information related to IT requests.

In the workflow we have created "Collect data from user" tasks.

When the user clicks on the hyperlink associated to the form in question, it launches the form in InfoPath if they have it installed.

We wish to override this, and have our forms load in the browser, just like an individual who dosen't have InfoPath installed on their computer.

I have seen blogs, in which you can append ?OpenIn=Browser to the end of the URL, but I am unsure where I am exactly suppose to do this.

Any other possible suggestions or solutions?

Edited:

What I orginally wanted to created was a feature only available for InfoPath. I thought something like this would exist for browser forms but I was mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That OpenIn=Browser is correct.

You need to have it in the link that user clicks on to open the form. In addition to OpenIn=Browser, you can use Source=SOMEURL, it will also open the form in browser and after closing the form, user is redirected to the Source URL.

Example:

```
<a href="http://servername/sites/SiteCollection/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XsnLocation=~sitecollection/FormLibrary/Forms/template.xsn&SaveLocation=~sitecollection/FormLibrary&Source=~sitecollection/FormLibrary">CLICK HERE TO FILL IN THE FORM</a>
```

Will open the form in browser, and redirect user to ~sitecollection/FormLibrary after closing the form.

[More information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms772417.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Jussi, but specifically where do I make this change, as in where in SharePoint Designer, or the SharePoint site that I make this modification?

Comment: I was thinking that could be put inside Content Editor Web Part as a simple link. Or in Links web part as one link. Would that work in your case?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the solutions outlined [here](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/browserforms/allow-force-browser-enabled-form-open-in-browser.htm), but it might not work given that your link is autogenerated in a task. You will not be able to append ?OpenIn=Browser either for the same reason.

Other users seem to have run into this problem, one solution is oultine [here](http://vksampath.blogspot.com/2009/08/force-sharepoint-infopath-forms-to.html). It's a bit involved though.

See also this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772417.aspx)

Edit: Collect Data is a simple task is not an editable task subprocess. You can still get to the custom task's display form (if you edit the custom task's Content Type in SPD) and specify your own deployed aspx page. In there, it would be possible to directly insert  javascript to rewrite the link and append OpenIn=Browser. This would affect that task type only.

Comment: Addendum: If you have SP2010, you can edit the internal workflow for that activity and I think get to the task's email body. You might be able to edit the link to append the OpenIn=Browser there.

Comment: I do have SP2010, Any Idea how to get to a tasks email body?

Comment: You would make the change in SPD. You can create the URL as a variable using the format that Jussi mentions below and add it into the body of the task as Louis mentions.

Comment: Sorry, I just opened SPD and the Collect Data action uses the custom task wizard, not the task subprocess as do the Approbation or Feedback actions. You will not be able to edit that, my bad :(

Comment: Edited original answer to add another possible lead.